# Strongloop - Loopback: How does one user view another user?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Let's say I have a social app where users connect with friends on their contacts to do something. How do those users find each other? So far no user can see another user. What is the best way to do this?

It's not answered in the documentation that I can find anywhere. I've looked and searched and searched Google. I don't know if I'm looking for it wrong or what but I HAVE in fact researched it all I can and I don't know that I can show any further research effort than I have already made.  There isn't a lot of Loopback JS use or questions on Stackoverflow.

If I GET the user model whether it's extended to a model called people or whether I just use the built in user model, I get this error when I query from the explorer using the GET method on my person model:

```
{   
"error": {
        "name": "Error",
        "status": 401,
        "message": "Authorization Required",
        "statusCode": 401,
        "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
        "stack": "Error: Authorization Required at...    } 
}
```

It doesn't even matter if I add this to the person.json in the model (and I'm not even sure if I should be doing this):

```
{
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "__get__People",
      "model": "Person"
    },
```

What is the problem here? What is recommended? How do users connect with each other in Loopback?

Comment: I would suggest narrowing your question down a bit. Instead of asking how users connect with each other, ask about a specific part of that process, such as allowing a user to see a list of other users, or whatever your actual requirement is. "How to connect with each other" is a bit broad because it could mean searching for other users or linking to other users which are two very different problems.

Comment: I think I did that. I pointed to the error I get when I do a GET on the person model that is an extension of the built in user model. This is pretty specific. I want a user to be able to "add a friend" so to speak. As is, by default, nobody can see each other.

Comment: Right, but "adding a friend" requires both being able to *find* a friend, and being able to associate one user to another. therefore, two different questions.

Comment: Yeah. I'd assume that finding a friend is the first step towards associating a friend. So that's the first question. How do you find them first? That's basically my main question. I can't do that in the explorer, it gets that error.